# i could not resolve this bundling error with react navigation v4

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-navigation-stack` from `App.js`: react-navigation-stack could not be found within the project.

i tried removing the node modules and reinstalling them, clearing the cache, trying the same in a new fresh project but no result

Package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "navigator",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-screens": "1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

App.js

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
    import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
    import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
    import ComponentScreen from './src/screens/ComponentScreen';


    const navigator = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Home: HomeScreen
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
          title: 'App'
        }
      }
    );

    export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `package.json` does not have the module you want to use. You need to install a module.

```
yarn add react-navigation-stack
```

or

```
npm install react-navigation-stack
```

Comment: Thank You sir, that is the one. But i am new to stack overflow so my votes are not displayed

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react-navigation-stack

npm install react-navigation-stack --save
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer and add some description about the code. Code only answers are discouraged.