# react-navigation/stack could not be found, eventhough I've installed it

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

Hello everyone I am following an online tutorial about react native but I ran into a problem:

```
\DUH\src\navigation\Navigator.tsx: @react-navigation/stack could not be found within the project or in these dire
ctories:
  node_modules
  ..\..\..\..\node_modules
   6 |   createStackNavigator,
   7 |   StackNavigationProp,
>  8 | } from '@react-navigation/stack';
     |         ^
   9 |
  10 | import * as routes from './routes';
  11 | import {SelectImageScreen} from '../screens/SelectImageScreen';
```

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "DUH",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.13.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

As you can see under dependencies I do in fact have react-navigation-stack installed:
`"react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"`

My question is: How can I fix this error??

I did install react-navigation-stack using this command:
`npm install react-navigation-stack`, which I found on this post: [i could not resolve this bundling error with react navigation v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58254850/i-could-not-resolve-this-bundling-error-with-react-navigation-v4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have installed wrong package: You need to install `@react-navigation/stack`, not `react-navigation-stack`. These two packages are not the same.

```
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

or

```
yarn add @react-navigation/stack
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac and developing for iOS, you also need to install the pods (via Cocoapods) to complete the linking.

```
npx pod-install ios
```

more info: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/